# Is this auth token ssl implementation safe

Tags: php, ssl, oauth, access-token

```
<?php

define('AES_256_CBC', 'aes-256-cbc');

// both stored in a file on server
$encryption_key = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(32); 
$iv = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(openssl_cipher_iv_length(AES_256_CBC)); 

$user_id = 1123;
$exp     = time() + (365 * 24 * 60 * 60);

$data = [
    "user_id" => $user_id,
    "exp"     => $exp,
];
$json = json_encode($data);

$token = openssl_encrypt($json, AES_256_CBC, $encryption_key, 0, $iv);
$base = base64_encode($token);
// at this point send the token to the client to use for further auth
$tokenDecoded = base64_decode($base);
$clear = openssl_decrypt($tokenDecoded, AES_256_CBC, $encryption_key, 0, $iv);
$sessionData = json_decode($clear);

?>
```

Everything occurs over an SSL HTTPS connection with signed certificate.

Comment: This question is maybe better asked on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: yep posted there too. I'll remove from here if suited in a day or two depending on given answers

Comment: Even though the code itself looks good, I feel a some kind of tension thinking that someone somehow will get access to your $encryption_key and will compromise "exp". I would probably prefer to have random tokens in Redis, for example, with auto-expire.